# how do i take a list of values from an array in one method and put those values into a new array from my main method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayAndGoParking
{

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
       int choice=0;
       int numCars=0;
       String Plates[]=new String[50];
       String ccNumbers[]=new String[50];
       Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);


        choice = printMenu();
        if(choice==1) {
            numCars=addCars(Plates,ccNumbers,numCars,b);
        }

    }

    public static int printMenu()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Park and Go Parking");
        System.out.println("Park from 6 - Midnight for a flat fee of $4.00");

        System.out.println("1. Register your vehicle");
        System.out.println("2. Verify vehicle registration");

        System.out.print("Hello enter a Selection: ");
        choice = s.nextInt();

        if(choice==1) {
            System.out.println("Register your vehicle");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Verify your registration");
        }

        return choice;
    }


   public static int addCars (String [] plates,String [ ] ccNumbers, int numCars, Scanner keyboard)
   {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter your plate number: ");
        plates[numCars]=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your Credit Card Number ($4.00 charge): ");
        ccNumbers[numCars]=s.nextLine();



        System.out.println("Thank you, your plate " +plates[numCars]+ " has been added to the lot");

        numCars++;


        return numCars;



    }
```

So pretty much what i want to happen is i want whatever the user enters for the plate number and ccNumber in the addCars method to be stored in the plates and ccNumber arrays in the main method. Sorry if i sound like i dont know what i am talking about, i am brand new to programming and am learning.

Answer (score 3):

GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR talks about the direct question you asked, but a much better approach to solving your problem would be to rework your code a little bit. Instead of passing everything around as parameters to your methods, you can set them up as properties of the object PayAndGoParking. This lets you just access them directly by changing their scope to the entire class, rather than just a single method.

In general you want to stay away from just dropping "static" on everything to make it work. Its a special keyword for a reason (and no its not because it just makes everything work :). Check out my sample code below and see how I would do it. Feel free to ask any questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PayAndGoParking {
    private String Plates[];
    private String ccNumbers[];
    private int numCars;

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        PayAndGoParking park = new PayAndGoParking();
        //set the defaults
        park.Plates = new String[50];
        park.ccNumbers =new String[50];
        park.numCars=0;

        int choice = park.printMenu();

        if(choice==1)
            park.addCars();

        //since arrays start at 0, this will print out the first license and cc number added
        System.out.println(park.Plates[0]);
        System.out.println(park.ccNumbers[0]);
    }

    public int printMenu()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Park and Go Parking");
        System.out.println("Park from 6 - Midnight for a flat fee of $4.00");

        System.out.println("1. Register your vehicle");
        System.out.println("2. Verify vehicle registration");

        System.out.print("Hello enter a Selection: ");
        choice = s.nextInt();

        if(choice==1)
            System.out.println("Register your vehicle");
        else
            System.out.println("Verify your registration");

        return choice;
    }

    public void addCars() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your plate number: ");
        Plates[numCars]= s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your Credit Card Number ($4.00 charge): ");
        ccNumbers[numCars]= s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Thank you, your plate " +Plates[numCars]+ " has been added to the lot");

        numCars++;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, better approach, i was just thinking about how to resolve the error in my code :p

Comment: Quick question, when i try to compile your code it says there is an error at park.numCars=0; in main. "Cannot find symbol- variable numCars"

Comment: As long as the object you created is named "park" and you have the line 'private int numCars;` up at the top everything should be fine. I just tried copy/pasting the sample from here into a new editor and it compiled ok. Tough to help without seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: never mind i figured it out. I changed the name of the class to differentiate from the PayAndGoParking class i have created. I didn't change the name of your object to match. Thanks though, man i'm coming to this site more often, tons of helpful people :).

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark this as the right answer :P

Answer (score 1):

```
String Plates[]=new String[50];
   String ccNumbers[]=new String[50];
```

your Plates and ccNumber arrays are **local variable(method variables)** confined to the **method scope only** i.e., you cannot access them outside **main** method.  make them your **static instance varibles** to access them any where in the class.

```
public class PayAndGoParking {
 static String Plates[]=new String[50];
 static  String ccNumbers[]=new String[50];
public static void main(String Args[]) {
 // code in your main
}
public static int addCars (String [] plates,String [ ] ccNumbers, int numCars, Scanner keyboard) { 
// you  can now access ccNumber and Plates array here.
}
```

### Variable Scopes:

1. static variables - lives as far as the class itself lives.
2. Instanve variables - lives as far as the instace of the class lives
3. local variables or method variables - lives with in the method.
4. Block variables - lives only with in the block

Comment: thank you. Do you know how i could print out the array values of Plates and ccNumbers after they have been stored?. I just want to make sure they are being stored haha.

Comment: just iterate over them after you call your addwhatever method in the main, however, @thedan answer seems to be much neater, i would recommend you to read his approach. :)